# Wicket - Panel not replaced the second time

Tags: wicket, panel

I have a simple modal popup which can be closed by a button. On the page where modal is going to be displayed there is a placeholder  with an id. When the page first loads i addOrReplace an empty Panel. Then, in response to proper action I swap this panel with the modal panel. Then I close the panel and swap it again with another empty panel. Everything works fine. But here's the strange thing - when I do this the second time, the modal panel opens normally, but when I press close it does not close even if it is replaced by the new empty panel and added to the target - but it worked before! When I press same button again, everything crashes not being able to find component for markup for the modal (but there should be no markup for it anymore!)

I have thought about it all day yet I still haven't found the reason for all this. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
private void swapToDummyPopupContainer() {
    currentPopupContainer = new DummyPanel("popupContainer");
    addOrReplace(currentPopupContainer);
}

private void swapToCreationPopupContainer(final FCalendarEvent event) {
    EventCreationPopup popup = new EventCreationPopup("popupContainer", event) {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 965466080498078142L;

        @Override
        public void onDataSubmit(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
            AvailabilityDTO model = getModel();
            event.setTitle(model.getDescription());
            pushNewEventToModel(model);
            availabilityMapping.put(event.getId(), model);
            FCalendarEventActions.addEvent(target, fcalendar, event);
            swapToDummyPopupContainer();
            target.add(currentPopupContainer);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
            swapToDummyPopupContainer();
            target.add(currentPopupContainer);
        }

    };
    currentPopupContainer = popup;
    addOrReplace(currentPopupContainer);
}

@Override
        protected void onRangeSelection(AjaxRequestTarget target, Date startDate, Date endDate,
                boolean isAllDay) {
            final FCalendarEvent event = new FCalendarEvent();
            swapToCreationPopupContainer(event);
            target.add(currentPopupContainer);
        }
```

As for  the markup there's

```
<wicket:container wicket:id="popupContainer" />
```

in the parent panel and both panels to be swapped are defined like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:wicket="http://wicket.apache.org/dtds.data/wicket-xhtml1.4-strict.dtd">
<wicket:panel>

</wicket:panel>

</html>
```

at the end of the modal markup (before closing tag) there is javascript, but I don't believe it has anything to do with it:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var $modal = $('#eventCreationPopup');
    $modal.modal('setting', {
        selector : {
            close : '',
            approve : '',
            deny : ''
        }
    });
    $modal.modal("show");
</script>
```

Comment: Please add some code (Java and Markup). Just from the description it's very hard if not impossible to find out what's going on.

Comment: Try to call setOutputMarkupPlaceholderTag(true) on your panel.

Comment: I did it but it didn't help. There was setOutputMarkupId set before that too.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot attach an JavaScript event to

```
<wicket:container wicket:id="popupContainer" />
```

because wicket:container has no real tag in the final markup you generate by Wicket. setOutputMarkupPlaceholderTag(true) has no effect in this case.

Change it to the DIV tag:

```
<div wicket:id="popupContainer"></div>
```

Comment: That sounded promissing but it didn't help either.